# Android mobile navigation - NavController Action class not generated

Tags: java, android, navigation

I'm using the NavController in a mobile application where I have a fragment with two navigation options to another fragment. I have created both actions in the mobile_navigation.xml but I can get the Action class generated.

Hope you understand.

This is my screen, I want to go to the same fragment when clicking the button or the card.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you have below dependencies in your build.gradle file? This might cause this classes not to generate.

```
 implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.2.0"
 implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.2.0"
```

Comment: First I had below dependencies, I moved them and it worked! But suddenly stopped working again without changing the gradle file.

Comment: What do you mean you moved them? Did you sync your gradle after adding them?

Comment: I changed the order of the dependencies so the navigation ones are the last, yes I sync my gradle and it worked! But suddenly stopped working.

Comment: Order of dependencies doesnt matter, so that's not the problem. Can you show me your build.gradle file?

Comment: I would suggest moving navigation plugin out of dependencies block to the top of the file, see if it helps

Comment: Still not working, I'll try to create another project to recreate this

Answer (score 0):

Here is my gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.go.accesoapp"
        minSdkVersion 18
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0"
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    implementation 'me.ydcool.lib:qrmodule:latest.integration'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs"
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.0.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like in your **build.gradle** file, the safeargs plugin: `apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs"` is under dependencies. Try moving it out of the dependencies to the top of the gradle file.